# Что делает tracer() в Python (turtle)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, методы, turtle

Сейчас я изучаю черепашку. Я видел, как кто-то использовал tracer в одной из задач.
Я хочу спросить: что такое tracer и с чем его едят?

Comment: думаю стоит почитать документацию или статьи по первому запросу в гугл https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/turtle-tracer-function-in-python/

Comment: @maestro, там всё по английски...

Comment: @ВадимТкаченко : 1) если времени на изучение языка нет - можно использовать встроенный переводчик страниц Google. Мне он вчера прекрасно сайт с китайского перевёл по Python (на английский, правда, но с английского на русский перевёд нормально). 2) имеет смысл язык таким образом (читая сайты на английском) поучить, он программисту нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `tracer()` настраивает трассировку линии черепахи.

### Аргументы

Метод принимает 2 аргумента.

Первый аргумент (bool) - если правдив, используется трассировка, если ложен - трассировка отключается.

Второй аргумент (float) - интервал между обновлениями отрисованного. Если равен нулю - автообновление отключается.

### Значение

Вы можете значительно ускорить отрисовку линий черепахи, ведь трассировка создана для демонстративных целей. При отключенной трассировке по умолчанию не обновляется экран, но экран можно обновить методом `update()` или задать автообновление вторым аргументом.

Comment: Если вопрос решен, нажмите галочку около ответа

Answer (score 0):

Например вы написали 'turtle код', который рисует много анимации и если его запустить например с максимальной скоростью speed(0) анимация всё равно будет отрисовываться медленно т.к. грубо говоря черепаха будет отрисовывать каждый пиксель у вас на глазах) Но если перед началом отрисовки установить tracer(5) то черепаха начнет, грубо говоря,  отрисовывать каждый пятый пиксель у вас на глазах, а остальное пропустит. Таким образом анимация пройдет из точки А в точку Б быстрей в 5 раз не по одному пикселю, а сразу шагнет на 5 пикселей. Есть еще задержка с которой она шагнёт на эти 5 пикселей. Это второй параметр tracer(5, delay) delay задаётся в микросекундах, если я правильно помню.